# How can I get all git branches that were merged in a branch from the last matching commit message

Tags: git

I want to get all branches that were merged in my master branch that since a commit for which I know the commit message. How can accomplish that?

Comment: git branch --merged master try this

Comment: To find the commit's hash ID, consider using one of the text-searching operations described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions). If the text is too complex for those, use `git log --grep`. Once you have the hash ID, you can go from there, but you'll have to define what you mean by "since".

Answer (score 0):

Starting from basics: branch is reference to head commit of this branch. Branch have no history, history of yours branch in git-log is generated based on commit parent field. Merge commits have references to theirs parents only by checksum, so if you hadn't wrote branch names in commit message there is no possibility to check which branches was merged.